# Powershell add pid of process to FileVersionInfo

Tags: powershell

I have to processes that run from different paths, that use the same executable. So if you use the -getname on the Get process - they show up as the same. WHen I use the FileVersionInfo property I can see which program is which.  I have to write a script that will kill the "DOG" process.

```
PS F:\>  Get-Process Casper -FileVersionInfo

ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
--------------   -----------      --------
5.5.2.0          5.5.2.33678      C:\Program Files (x86)\foo\DOG III\Casper.exe
5.5.4.1          5.5.4.4163       C:\Program Files\foo\CATS NG (PROD)\Casper.exe
```

How do I add the pid of each process, so I can isolate it and kill it if needed.

```
Get-Process Casper | Select Id
Id
--
16894
19456
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following:

```
Get-Process Casper | Select ProductVersion,FileVersion,Path,Id
```

If you run `Get-Process Casper | Get-Member`, you can see most of the properties available to the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object type. The bottom of the output contains some `ScriptProperty` types that you can access. Path, ProductVersion, and FileVersion are what show up when you use the `-FileVersionInfo` switch.

If you dislike the `Path` property name, you can rename it in your select statement:

```
Get-Process Casper | Select ProductVersion,FileVersion,@{n="FileName";e={$_.Path}},Id
```

You can use the `where()` method to narrow down your search by the path name:

```
(Get-Process Casper).where({$_.Path -like "*DOG III*"}) | 
   Select ProductVersion,FileVersion,@{n="FileName";e={$_.Path}},Id
```

If you really only need the `Id` to pipe into another program, then you can use the following:

```
(Get-Process Casper).where({$_.Path -like "*DOG III*"}).Id | Some-Command
```